# Using .shift() to Update an Array's Elements

Tags: javascript, function

I'm struggling with a pretty simple issue, but I've been going over and over it and can't seem to figure out what to do.

http://jsbin.com/harokap/edit?js,output

```
var parkRides = [["Bumbling Boats", 20], ["Scary Cyclone", 45], 
["Cloudy Crevase", 10], ["Crazy Crapshoot", 5]];

var fastPassQueue = ["Crazy Crapshoot", "Cloudy Crevase", "Bumbling Boats",
    "Crazy Crapshoot"];

function writeTicket(allRides,passRides,pick){
    if(pick == passRides[0]){
        passRides.shift();
        return function(){
            alert("Lucky you! You got a Fast Pass to " + pick + "!");
        };
    }else{
        for(var i = 0; i < allRides.length; i++){
            if(pick == allRides[i][0]){
                return function(){
                    alert("Now printing ticket for " + pick + ". Your wait time is about " + allRides[i][1] + " minutes.");
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

var rideChoice = "Crazy Crapshoot";

var ticket = writeTicket(parkRides,fastPassQueue,rideChoice);

ticket();
```

In that code I have an array called "fastPassQueue" that I want to update with passRides.shift() inside of the "writeTicket" function.

I want writeTicket to recognize that the first element has been removed from fastPassQueue every time I run the function (and subsequently run the else condition after the first time the function is called), but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried adding fastPassQueue into the beginning of the function, which works IF I run the function first the original way and THEN add it into the function, but I can't figure out how to make it work from the start...

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Could include any relevant code in your question and not just a jsfiddle? In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just 
include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: I think your code is working. Add `console.log(fastPassQueue);` before and after calling `writeTicket()` then you can see `fastPassQueue` is changed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as not returning a function inside a `for` loop, create the string instead, and always return the function

```
var parkRides = [
    ["Bumbling Boats", 20],
    ["Scary Cyclone", 45],
    ["Cloudy Crevase", 10],
    ["Crazy Crapshoot", 5]
];

var fastPassQueue = ["Crazy Crapshoot", "Cloudy Crevase", "Bumbling Boats", "Crazy Crapshoot"];

function writeTicket(allRides, passRides, pick) {
    if (pick == passRides[0]) {
        passRides.shift();
        return function () {
            alert("Lucky you! You got a Fast Pass to " + pick + "!");
        };
    } else {
        var match = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < allRides.length; i++) {
            if (pick == allRides[i][0]) {
                match = "Now printing ticket for " + pick + ". Your wait time is about " + allRides[i][1] + " minutes.";
            }
        }

        return function () {
            alert(match);
        };
    }
}

var rideChoice = "Bumbling Boats";

var ticket = writeTicket(parkRides, fastPassQueue, rideChoice);

ticket();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g0nb09ze/)

Comment: I tried running the code you provided with var rideChoice = "Crazy Crapshoot" (fastPassQueue[0]), but when I call the function the second time it still runs the if condition, so I keep getting "Lucky you! You got a Fast Pass to Crazy Crapshoot!" I'm trying to get passRides.shift() to remove that element so that when the function is called a second/third/fourth time, it runs the else condition because "Crazy Crapshoot" has been removed from the fastPassQueue array.

Comment: Okay, I probably don't get it then, I thought this is what you wanted -> **http://jsfiddle.net/g0nb09ze/1/**

Comment: This is super close to what I want, but I was trying to figure out how to show an updated message by ONLY running ticket() (a second time) and not needing ticket2(). Is that possible?